# Rails - How to get virtual attributes too when using find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to include virtual variables too when trying to find an object. e.g if **status** is a virtual attribute in rails model then Object.find(1) should return object with **status**.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea behind virtual attributes are that they are not stored in the database. There are many use cases where you want a temporary attribute (injecting dependencies etc.)

If you need to have an attribute populated when fetching with `.find` or any other database retrieval method then you need to make it a regular attribute and store it.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.find()` returns an object with the values currently stored in the database. Therefore, any extra attribute or state stored outside the database will not be visible.

You need to store the `status` attribute in the database if you want to be able to access it after you fetch the record from the database.